# Display all x values of a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know it has already been asked, but I could not solve my problem. 
I have three pandas column, One with dates, and other with values.
I can get my graph with the two curves depending on date.

However, I cannot display all dates in the x axis. Can you help me?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




# mau_file is the pandas dataframe with three columns.

plt.figure()

mau_file.plot(x='month_date', y=['mau', 'nb_migs'], figsize=(10,5), grid=True)
plt.set_xticklabels(mau_file['month_date'])
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: post head of you data frame, and draw expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, `plt.xticks()` is used to display x axis values.

As I'm not sure it is 100% compatible with a pandas structure, you may need to store your data in a classical table or a numpy array.

[Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) of `plt.xticks()`

EDIT : It is possible to chose the orientation of the labels.

For exemple `plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')` will give you vertical labels.

Comment: Thanks ! Now, can I make the labels be displayed more verticaly, to make the designe better? Because with only horizontal dates, there is not enough space for every dates.

Comment: Edited my answer to show you how to rotate labels. Don't hesitate to mark this answer as accepted if it helped you.